# Cannot authenticate with xero-node integration

Tags: node.js, xero-api

I'm trying to integrate Xero API into my node app, using the official [xero-node](https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node) library.

Following the docs, I registered a public app, supplied `consumerKey` and `consumerSecret` to config, tried both the sample app and built my own, but getting the same error:

```
{ oauth_problem: 'token_rejected',
     oauth_problem_advice: 'Token has not been provided' }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help a bit more if you post your code that you're trying to execute.

Public applications require you to go through a 3 legged OAuth process (e.g. get Request Token, Get Access Token and make the request).

It's possible that you're trying to do a 2 legged OAuth process and this is what is causing the issue.

There's a blog post that might assist. It takes a user through the process of setting up a Public app using the xero-node library:

https://devblog.xero.com/build-super-sweet-accounting-apps-with-xero-and-node-js-2ac6e673bee

Comment: Thanks mate, it's very helpful. My problem was that I didn't find the part about `getRequestToken` and `setAccessToken` in the docs, so I just missed them. Btw the blog post is awesome!

Comment: Thanks. Glad you figured it out.